# java json error on casting

Tags: java, json, json-simple

My Java code look like below:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
String jsonMember = strUrl;
String strMember = readUrl(jsonMember);

if (!Validator.isEmpty(strMember)) {
    Object obj = parser.parse(strMember);
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray jsonArrayMember = (JSONArray) jo.get("member");
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayMember.size(); j++) {
        JSONObject memberObj = (JSONObject) jsonArrayMember.get(j);
        String name = memberObj.get("name").toString();
        String age = memberObj.get("age").toString();
    }
}
```

the **strUrl** look like below:

```
{
    "team": {
        "team_id": "2",
        "team_name": "volcanoe"
    },
    "member": [
        {
            "name": "Samantha",
            "age": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```

it gives me error as below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

for line:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayMember = (JSONArray) jo.get("member");
```

i was trying to read the member element of the json, but strangely get the boolean error. None of the json are using boolean, they are json object.

**extra info:**
the code work fine on development server, but when put to production, it caused above error. Is there anything to do with the code or the library/jdk imported?

any help would be great.

Comment: I don't have any exception with the json string. I think your problem is string itself, check the real input string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you

```
String jsonString="{\"team\": {\"team_id\": \"2\",\"team_name\": \"volcanoe\"},\"member\": [{\"name\": \"Samantha\",\"age\": \"20\"}]}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray jsonArrayMember=jsonObject.getJSONArray("member");

System.out.println(jsonArrayMember);
```

can you please change your org.json jar file to the one in this link [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) and try again hope this will solve your problem

Comment: what version of java jdk that org.json works, because i try to run it i get:
Cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getJSONArray(String)
location: variable jsonObject of type JSONObject

Comment: am using jdk 1.8. So, try jdk 1.8 and later versions

Comment: we are using the same jdk version.. still get that error, do you have any idea? thanks for helping..

Comment: nvm solved.. --> import org.json.JSONArray; thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

As "team" is a json object {}, "member" is a json array [],

You should try this

```
JSONArray jsonArrayMember = jo.getJSONArray("member");
```